# Can't install Kontakt Android SDK using Gradle on Android Studio

Tags: maven, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to install the Android SDK from Kontakt into a project in Android studio. I'm following the (seemingly basic) instructions on the Kontakt site here:

http://docs.kontakt.io/android-sdk/quickstart/#installing-the-sdk---android-studio

In brief, these steps say add `maven { url 'http://repo.kontakt.io/repository/internal/' }` in the `repositories` in your top-level build file, and add to add `compile 'com.kontakt.sdk.android:library:1.0.5'` in the `dependencies` in the main module build file.

However, when I try to sync my project with the updated files, it fails with an error message:

```
Error:Failed to find: com.kontakt.sdk.android:library:1.0.5
```

I tried with a totally fresh project and the same issue.

I'm guess this all has something to do with the fact that the instructions are written for Android's 0.12 version of the Gradle tools, but I'm using v1.1.0. I'm not across the detail of Gradle, so so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that path to Kontakt.io public repository should be added to `allprojects` section instead of `buildscript`.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://repo.kontakt.io/repository/internal/' }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MickByrne, did you managed to solve the problem? Was this answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure so don't shoot me:P

I think adding this line:

```
-->compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.kontakt.sdk.android:library:1.0.6'
```

Directly above the gradle project I wanted to compile fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Kontakt.io Android Proximity SDK https://github.com/kontaktio/kontakt-android-sdk on GitHub.

- Click the Download ZIP button
- Un-zip the file to a temporary location.
- Add the jar file in your Android Studio Project.
- File -> New Module -> Import .JAR/ .AAR Package -> Click Next -> Browse the SDK path (2.1.1) -> Finish (Take time to add in the project)
- Then, Add module in dependencies
- Right Click on Project Name -> Open Module Settings -> Under the list (Modules) -> Click on Dependencies -> Click on '+' -> Module Dependency -> Add Kontakt.io-android-sdk

Now Build your project It worked for me to kontakt io SDK. If anybody find the way to do this as Gradle build, please let me know.